# how to change particular column cell foreground and background color in oracle forms 6i using visual attribute

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using this code

```
IF :SAL > 4000 THEN
     SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('EMP.SAL',VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE,'VA_COLOR');
END IF;
```

This code is colored all column, but i want to color only particular cell where i am changing the salary value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can use `SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY`

```
set_item_instance_property('EMP.SAL', current_record, visual_attribute,'VA_COLOR' );
```